# Size and shape prediction (OpenCV or Tensorflow/Keras)

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

## Introduction

I am newbie in statistics and NN.
I will describe my prolem below.

## Problem

I want to find when the object on the video (images as well), will have following parameters:

- the smallest diameter,
- when the shape is closest to circle,
- when the object have highest brightness.

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ZrZ.jpg

## Possible approaches

I started with neural networks (tensorflow) and object detection module, which detect objects similiar to circles, then I calculate the area of bounidng box. Then I started exploring mask RCNN networks and I am considering to obtain area of the mask. But it didn't solve my problem.

## Asking for advice

The question is how to add other parameters? Like brightness or shape? Could you please give me some suggestions? Research papers, articles or post your thoughts in this field. I am waiting for deep conversation

Many thanks!

## Update 1

To detect circles Hough Transform can be used.
To find the smallest diameter I should consider thinness ratio.
Any other thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not a discussion forum; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), where you will also notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider learning basics of image processing and computer vision first.
Locating circles on the image is a basic problem, so it's well-studied and has plenty of robust solutions.
There is no even need to use NN in your particular case (find a circle-like shapes at synthetic image you provided).

Refer to Wikipedia [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform) to start with basics.

Comment: I am familiar with Circle Hough Transform, but still, it doesn't answer how to find the best circle. I am considering thinness ratio, maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d

OpenCV HoughCircles() function returns detected circles with their radius. I can't get your idea of 'best' circle. Using radius you can find smaller or bigger circle. If you want to take brightness in account you may use some metric: M = radius * (brightness / 255); or something more sophisticated with weights added for radius and brightness components: M = (2.0 * radius) * (0.7 * (brightness / 255)) to make one component's impact more valuable.